# How can I declare StorageClass with Fibre Channel (FC) in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up Kubernetes with SAN using FC.
From the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/
It seems like Storage Class does not support FC, right?
If not, could some guys show me how to define Storage Class that support FC?
I'm stuck here.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes docs mentioned about [fc (fibre channel)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#fc) so it can be achieve. Docs also redirecting to examples on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/fibre_channel).

Regarding use of `storageClass` I don't think it is possible (as you mentioned, its not supporting Fibre Channel). Solution might be write driver using [FlexVolume](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-storage/flexvolume.md), however I've read that there is driver for `FC` on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/volume/fc/fc.go). It would be worth to check it.